# Windows 10 Universal App Unit Testing project

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I can't seem to find any information on this.. I am using it to test my Universal app but it comes with a XAML file and when I run the Unit Test it opens some screen... What is that for ? I don't need that.. I just want to unit test my code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the xaml file has something in common with UI tests, but you can still add some unit tests into that project and run them, it will start the application and blank screen will be displayed for a moment, but unit tests will run too.

Comment: But I wonder why does it need to load the app and not just run the code like a normal unit test? Also I have to manually stop it everytime it runs..  Just strange I can't find any info on it

Comment: Strange to me too, but looks like there is no other option for now. But do you really have to stop it manually? For me, after the tests pass, the window close automatically.

Comment: The windows close but the tests never stopped running.. I'm just going to avoid using it for now and put the testing directly in the app